# Search Kit - List of Events with their real total amounts

Tags: civievent, searchkit, line-items

## **What we want**

We want to have a Search that shows us the upcoming Events with the Total Amount paid for each event. Something like this:

[image]

## **Our problem**

While listing the upcoming events is easy, showing what our Partipants paid for them is quite troublesome.

To be able to show what the Participants paid, we have to do it via Line Items. We constructed our Search like the following one:

[image]

What this Search shows is what the Participants should have paid, but not what actually paid.

For example, an event costs 100€, but the Participant only paid 80€. This search would add the 100€ instead the real 80€.

Our question is, how we can add the real amount instead of the cost of the event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want can be accomplished by filtering out transactions with an incomplete status, like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This really helped!